Office 365 - Send email from alias through SMTP
I'm setting up the following helm chart :
https://github.com/jp-gouin/helm-openldap
I'm trying to make sending reset token with ltb-ssp work. At that point, I'm able to send a reset email to a user by setting up the env vars to use Office 365 as a SMTP server. I created a general tooling user which I added an alias for ssp. I also enabled the use of alias in the Exchange Admin Center. However, despite having set up the env vars for using my alias as sender address, the reset email is still noted as sent by the main tooling address.
Here are the env vars for ltb-ssp :
- name: SMTP_AUTH_ON
  value: "true"
- name: SMTP_HOST
  value: "smtp.office365.com"
- name: SMTP_PORT
  value: "587"
- name: SMTP_USER
  value: "tooling@my.domain"
- name: SMTP_PASS
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: my-secrets
      key: SMTP_PASS
- name: MAIL_FROM
  value: "ssp@my.domain"
- name: IS_BEHIND_PROXY
  value: "true"
- name: SITE_URL
  value: "https://ssp.my.domain"

I also tried to set SMTP_USER as the alias but got an authentication error.
In the details of the email, I can see that the email is sent by the alias and that the return path is the main email :
From: SelfService Password <ssp@my.domain>
Return-Path: tooling@my.domain

The email in outlook is noted as sent by the main email. Is there a way to make it noted as sent by the alias ?
EDIT
I tried sending the email to a gmail account instead of the office address. The email is actually noted as sent by the alias so I guess this is more of an outlook configuration
